# Why can't I connect to my SQL Server with Windows Authentication using Domain Username?

Tags: php, sql-server

This is my connection php :

```
$serverName = "SERVER";

$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Databasenamehere");
```

My setup on the laptop is wamp server with latest updates.

I am trying to connect to the SQL Server using Windows Authentication. The server is on a domain. My machine is on the same domain. The user, that it is trying to connect to is also on the domain. The user has all the needed permissions to access the SQL Server (SQL Server 2012). I can access the server from within Windows logged on with this user. I can ping the server.

My error :

> Login failed for user 'MDOMAIN\LOCALPC$'. [message] =>
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for
>   user 'MDOMAIN\LOCALPC$'.

The above does not make sense. The above should say : MDOMAIN\Username and not LOCALPC$ as that is the laptops computer name.

What I've tried so far :

1.) `runas /netonly /user:MDOMAIN\Username"C:\wamp\wampmanager.exe"`

2.) `NET USE \\DBWHK01 /USER:MDOMAIN\Username`

3.) Created a Windows credential with the FQN of the server and then MDOMAIN\Username and the password.

Can't I specific somewhere to force the system (wherever) to use "MDOMAIN\Username" instead of "MDOMAIN\LOCALPC$" ? SQL Auth is currently not an option. And ODBC_CONNECT would need recoding of the entire site as all is encoded in SQLSVR so that is also not an option. I don't know why the system doesn't parse the Windows Authentication as is (as the user that is logged in). Not even the above runas and net use helped.

Comment: Your server use Apache?

Comment: you didnt mention which driver you use to make connection, you can use PDO for this

Comment: @Marco Mura : Yes, wamp uses Apache.

@meda : I connect with `sqlsrv_connect()`

Comment: maybe this comment can help -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php#57880

Comment: has the user logged into the local PC rather than the domain?

Comment: Your apache is probably running as a windows service and probably under the SYSTEM account. For that account the machine's credentials are used, not those of a particular user. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Marco Mura : You deserve a medal : Many thanks for that link it really helped. Thanks a lot ! How to choose your comment as solution ???

Comment: by the by: is there a reason you want/have to use the windows authentication instead of passing the credentials via the connectionInfo array?

Comment: @cyberion1985 posted an answer about that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solution -> php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php#57880

Comment: So , Marco Mura posted the link that lead to the solution.
What I did, I went to local services, located the wamp server apache service and then went to logon as and then specified the username and password as user that this service starts with. After that, everything worked perfectly.